# How to fix 'TS2769 No overload matches this call' when using react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-leaflet

I'm trying to implement a Leaflet map component on my react app. This is how my component looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "./styles.scss";

const position = [51.505, -0.09];

const LocationMap: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <section className="find-container container">
      <h2 className="find-title title">Find us</h2>
      <Map center={position} zoom={12}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
        />
      </Map>
    </section>
  );
};

export default LocationMap;
```

When I run "npm start", the project fail to compile, and shows this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<MapProps>): Map<MapProps, Map>', gave the following error.
    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'LatLng | LatLngLiteral | LatLngTuple | undefined'.
      Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: MapProps, context?: any): Map<MapProps, Map>', gave the following error.
    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'LatLng | LatLngLiteral | LatLngTuple | undefined'.
      Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'LatLngTuple'.  TS2769
```

Somebody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript complains since `center` property is declared as an array (`number[]`)  while it is expected to be of tuple type:

```
const position:[number,number] = [51.505, -0.09];
```

or `LatLngLiteral` type:

```
const position: LatLngLiteral = { lat: 51.505, lng: -0.09 };
```

or `LatLng` type:

```
const position = new LatLng(51.505,-0.09);
```

To summarize, to utilize `react-leaflet` with TypeScript the following packages needs to be installed:

- `leaflet` as a dependency
- `react-leaflet` and type definitions `@types/react-leaflet`

And last but no least, [as per documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) leaflet CSS file needs to be included, for instance, via `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
```